# Grunt install failure

Tags: npm, gruntjs

I'm trying to install Grunt using the following command:

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

I get this result:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: grunt-cli
npm ERR! No valid targets found.
npm ERR! Perhaps not compatible with your version of node?
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:488:10)
npm ERR!     at next_ (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:438:17)
npm ERR!     at next (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:415:44)
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:408:5
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:147:7)
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (/usr/lib/nodejs/graceful-fs.js:230:7)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /root/node/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-17-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "grunt-cli"
npm ERR! cwd /root/node
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.19
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! message No compatible version found: grunt-cli
npm ERR! message No valid targets found.
npm ERR! message Perhaps not compatible with your version of node?
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/node/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

Ideas? I know my Node and npm are installed correctly. I am using Ubuntu Linux 12.04 LTS with a standard LAMP installation and npm version v0.11.5-pre

Answer (score 12):

You're using an old version of node.js (`v0.6.19`). Grunt is only compatible with node.js `>= 0.8`. See this issue for a duplicate problem: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/723

Comment: That's odd, because I cloned and installed Node. Should be the latest version. But the issue was actually that $NODE_PATH was empty

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Id advise against using v0.11.5-pre though. That is a development version of node and those are known to break. Even numbered node versions are stable.

Comment: If using nvm , $NODE_PATH set or not , didn't affect, the installation was failing anyway... The issue in my case was setting nvm with sudo to use the -g switch, but nvm use of node version wasn't persistent between sessions .. that was causing a similar problem, once able to set nvm to use the right version "without sudo" .. it was all good...

Comment: @MasonPhillips Just ran into the same issue. "Installing" the latest version of `node` did not overwrite my existing old version in `/usr/bin/node`.

Answer (score 2):

**Ubuntu**

1. Setup with Ubuntu

`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -`

2. Then install with Ubuntu

`sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`

**Debian**

1. Update your Repository

`sudo apt-get install curl`

2. Update your source

`sudo curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -`

Source https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager

Answer (score 1):

Solved by adding export NODE_PATH= *Output of "which node"* to my .bashrc file

Comment: What was your output of "which node"?